# exporting a blog from a blogging platform to a website

Tags: wordpress, blog, looking-for-hosting, transfer, blogspot

I want to create a blog with my own domain and considere both the following alternatives:

**(a)** purchasing a domain, a host service and creating a **website from scratch** ;

**(b)** run a **blogger platform** like Wordpress and similar, create the blog and purchase the domain.

Since I can't figure out which solution is currently the best for me, I wonder:

- *if I opte for the* **(b)** *and then I'll change my mind in the future ->
  is it possible to **export all the content of the blog*** (b) *into my own website* (a) *later, keeping the domain name, without any remarkable trouble?
  (I mean keeping the blog and the name unchanged, except for the fact that is no longer holded by Wordpress or everyone else)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to export all the content of the blog (b) into my own website (a) later, keeping the domain name, without any remarkable trouble?

The answer will depend on your skill level with this sort of thing, but it is more than possible to go from a CMS-based site to any other kind of site.  At worst, you will need to copy/paste your content.  Usually there will be tools or scripts available to you to more automatically dump your content out in the desired format.